# Functions and conditions inside ngfor loop keeps executing infinitely

Tags: angular, typescript

i am working on advanced reporting kind of solution.

So basically i have created table using ngFor loop in which i have written some conditions which enables user to check details of clicked element based on expand and collapse

Problem is this conditions are executing infinite time, what i want is these conditions should be perform checking only once. Checking conditions infinitely is making performance degradation of UI.

Here is my code

```
<div class="row" style="position:relative; overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 30px;" >
   <div class="tg-wrap">
      <div class="zui-scroller">
         <div class="tg">
            <div class="report-row-header ">
               <div class="tg-kiyi sticky-col-1" >#</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('impressions') === true">Impressions</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('conversions') === true">Conversion</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi " *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('bids') === true">Bids</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi " *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('wins') === true">Wins</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('spend') === true">Spend</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('ecpa') === true">eCPA</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('ecpm') === true">eCPM</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('winrate') === true">Win Rate</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('clearrate') === true">Clear Rate</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('pixels') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'" >Loads</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('payout') === true">Payout</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('onehplus') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'">OnehPlus</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('clicks') === true">Clicks</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('cr') === true">CR</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('ctr') === true">CTR</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('OneDplus') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'">OneDplus</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('OneDless') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'">OneDless</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('ROI') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'">ROI</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi">Actions</div>
            </div>
            <div class="total-row ">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1 text-right" style="height: 52px;"></div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('impressions') === true">{{convertToDecimals(totalImpressions,2)}}</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('conversions') === true">{{convertToDecimals(totalConversions,2)}}</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('bids') === true">{{convertToDecimals(totalBids,2)}}</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('wins') === true">{{convertToDecimals(totalWins,2)}}</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('spend') === true">$ {{convertToDecimals(totalSpend,2)}}</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('ecpa') === true"> {{convertToDecimals(ecpa,2)}}</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('ecpm') === true"> {{convertToDecimals(ecpm,2)}}</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('winrate') === true"> {{convertToDecimals(win_rate,2)}} %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('clearrate') === true"> {{convertToDecimals(clear_rate,2)}} %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('pixels') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'"> {{convertToDecimals(totalPixels,2)}}</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('payout') === true ">$ {{convertToDecimals(totalPayout,2)}} </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('onehplus') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'"> 
                  {{convertToDecimals(totalOnehplus,2)}} %
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('clicks') === true">{{convertToDecimals(totalClicks,2)}}</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('cr') === true"> 
                  {{convertToDecimals(totalCR,3)}} %
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('ctr') === true"> 
                  {{convertToDecimals(totalCTR,3)}} %
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('OneDplus') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'" >{{convertToDecimals(totalOneDplus,2) }} %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('OneDless') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'">{{convertToDecimals(totalOneDless,2) }} %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('ROI') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'">
                  <span *ngIf="totalROI > 0" style="color:#4caf50 !important; font-weight: 400">+{{convertToDecimals(totalROI,2) }} %</span>
                  <span *ngIf="totalROI <= 0" style="color:#df514c !important; font-weight: 400">{{convertToDecimals(totalROI,2) }} %</span>
               </div>
                <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">N/A</div>
            </div>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let rData of reportData; let i = index; last as isLast" >
               <div class="report-row">
                  <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1">
                     <button 
                     class="btn report-btn-sm" 
                     *ngIf="checkIfHaveMoreSplits(this.splitOpt[0].id) !== 0 && rData.isCollapsed == true"
                     (click)="splitData(rowWiseFilterObj(rData,this.splitOpt[0].id),this.splitOpt[0].id,sFilters,splitOpt,i,rData,selectedDate)"
                     row="rData">+</button>
                     <button 
                     class="btn report-btn-sm" 
                     *ngIf="checkIfHaveMoreSplits(this.splitOpt[0].id) !== 0 && rData.isCollapsed == false" 
                     (click)="removeDynamicComponent(rData,i)"
                     >-</button>
                     <span *ngIf="this.splitOpt[0].id == 'campid'">{{rData['campaign_name']}}</span>
                     <span *ngIf="this.splitOpt[0].id !== '__time' && this.splitOpt[0].id !== 'campid'">{{rData[this.splitOpt[0].id]}}</span>
                     <span *ngIf="this.splitOpt[0].id === '__time'">

                        {{getCorrectDateTime( rData[this.splitOpt[0].id])}}
                     </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('impressions') === true">{{convertToDecimals(rData.impressions,2)}}</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('conversions') === true">{{convertToDecimals(rData.conversions,2)}}</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('bids') === true">{{convertToDecimals(rData.bids,2)}}</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('wins') === true">{{convertToDecimals(rData.wins,2)}}</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('spend') === true">$ {{convertToDecimals(rData.spend,2)}}</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('ecpa') === true">{{convertToDecimals(rData.ecpa,2)}}</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('ecpm') === true">{{convertToDecimals(rData.ecpm,2)}}</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('winrate') === true">{{convertToDecimals(rData.win_rate,2)}} %</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('clearrate') === true">{{convertToDecimals(rData.clear_rate,2)}} %</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('pixels') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'">{{convertToDecimals(rData.pixels,2)}}</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('payout') === true">$ {{convertToDecimals(rData.payout,2)}} </div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('onehplus') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser' ">{{convertToDecimals(rData.OneHplus,2)}} %</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('clicks') === true">{{convertToDecimals(rData.clicks,2)}}</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('cr') === true">{{convertToDecimals(rData.cr,3)}} %</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('ctr') === true">{{convertToDecimals(rData.ctr,3)}} %</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('OneDplus') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'">{{convertToDecimals(rData.OneDplus,2) }} %</div>
                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('OneDless') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'">{{convertToDecimals(rData.OneDless,2) }} %</div>

                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15" *ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('ROI') === true && _configService.getUserRole() !='advertiser'">
                     <span *ngIf="rData.ROI > 0" style="color:#4caf50; font-weight: 400">+{{convertToDecimals(rData.ROI,2) }} %</span>
                     <span *ngIf="rData.ROI <= 0" style="color:#df514c; font-weight: 400">{{convertToDecimals(rData.ROI,2) }} %</span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
                     <button class="btn btn-secondary m-btn m-btn--label-danger m-btn--bolder m-btn--uppercase btn-sm" disabled="disabled" > <i class="la la-ban"></i> </button>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div *ngIf="isLast" class="text-left col-12">
                  {{altrows("#ffffff","#f5f5f5")}}
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="m-link" (click)="loadmore()" style="margin:10px 60px 10px -15px;
                  background: #5ccdde;
                  color: #fff;
                  padding: 2px 10px;
                  font-size: 12px;" *ngIf="reportData.length > 19"> Load more </a>
               </div>
               <ng-template #dynamic ></ng-template>
            </ng-container>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Below is insights of functions and conditions are used

1) checkColumnVisibiliy(col) is used to display specific columns based on localstorage

2) checkIfHaveMoreSplits(nextsplit) is used to check to make sure that table row is expanded or not based on avability of nextsplit

3)convertToDecimals(number,decimal) it is used to convert long integer to user readable numbers

Please help

Comment: can you create a stackblitz example for that.

Comment: I will try, code is bit complicated so it will take while 
But i will try to build it on stackblitz

Comment: You can replace every `*ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('impressions') === true"` to just `*ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('impressions')"` as ngIf expects a boolean, you don't have to check again if the returned value is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use methods in your template, because each time Angular runs change detection, the method will be called, which can happen often. So actually this is not an infinite loop, the method just gets called on each change detection.

To avoid this, you need to change your code to handle the logic of methods in your component, and use variables in your template instead.

and also as in above comments always use this `*ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('impressions')"` and return boolean instead of this `*ngIf="checkColumnVisibiliy('impressions') === true"`

> Here in your example instead of taking this much variables you can use
>   one model and based on your condition make it true false(default false).  That will
>   be easier to use in your code

Comment: Check right if you tried it successfully and if not then tell me for improvisation